# My nested repeater isn't returning anything(Wordpress plugin ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater which I will show below which isn't returning any errors as well as it's not returning anything. (Echo not working)

I'm trying to show the sub field officetype but this is the setup:

Offices(repeater)->Officetypeinfo(repeater)->Multiple sub fields(E.g. officetype)

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong, please do tell me if you need more then what I provided.

```
<?php if( get_field('offices')): ?>
    <?php while( has_sub_field('offices')): ?>
        <?php if( get_sub_field('officetypeinfo')): ?>
            <?php while( has_sub_field('officetypeinfo')): ?>
                <?php
                    $show = the_sub_field('officetype');
                       echo $show;
                       the_sub_field('officetype');
                ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add `the_sub_field('officetype');` after `echo $show;`

Did you check that you're using the right field-names?
Try `var_dump('field-name');` to check where it goes wrong.

Comment: I afterwards realised my structure was incorrect and deleted the sub field officetypeinfo and fixed my structure by removing that as well from the while. Regardless thank you that helped me realise it back then.